# Clearcase: restoring a lost directory element

Tags: clearcase, mv, cleartool

I'm working with Clearcase 8.0.1 under RHEL7, and I'm facing an issue I can't explain.

In the static view I use, I lost a directory element by accidentally unchecking out its parent directory. As any orphaned element, this directory now stands in the *lost+found* directory of my VOB.

I tried to get it back by re-checking out the parent directory, and running the following command from the root of my view:

```
cleartool mv MyVob/lost+found/MyElement.uuid MyVob/ParentDirectory/MyElement
```

But I got the following error messages :

```
cleartool: Error: Moving a VOB element within a snapshot view requires both the source "/MyVob/lost+found/MyElement.uuid" and the destination directory "/MyVob/ParentDirectory" to be loaded.
cleartool: Error: Unable to move "MyVob/ParentDirectory" to "MyVob/ParentDirectory/MyElement".
```

What I don't understand is that both source and destination are loaded, as far as I can say (*cleartool ls* does give me the rule used lo load both).

Does anyone have an idea of what happens, and the way to obtain what I want?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well...
As often, the solution came up just after posting the question!

The problem I had is that my source element itself was checked out too. The rule used to load it was CHECKEDOUT, but it doesn't mean Clearcase considered it as loaded, in fact.

Sorry!